# Sharepoint 365 - Delete subfolders older than 30 days

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm totally new to Sharepoint and would appreciate any help.

I have a folder on my SP 365 site, "Requests", and it contains many subfolders and files. I want to delete all subfolders (and everything in them) created more than 30 days ago. How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create flow as following pictures show.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.